# What are the applications of Non Unique Factorization Domain (Non-UFD) in signal processing?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital, polynomial

Let $m$ be a composite, and $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is the residual ring of modular $m$. The $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is clearly a Non-UFD. What are the applications of the polynomial with coefficients defined on $\mathbb{Z}_m$ in  digital signal processing?

Or, what are the applications of algebraic structures on $\mathbb{Z}_m$ to digital signal processing  and other fields?

Comment: "What are the applications of..." are almost always questions that end up being too broad. In this case, this is basic algebra, and that permeates all of discrete math – and thus, all of DSP. Ask something more precise, please, that can have a complete answer.